# What happened to RouteCollection.MapAsyncRoute() in MVC Futures?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, routes, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-futures

I am working on upgrading an old project from MVC 1.0 to MVC 3.0 as well as from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0.  It has not gone very smoothly.

My current problem is that I cannot find a replacement for the extension method RouteCollection.MapAsyncRoute() which was located in Microsoft.Web.Mvc, the MVC Futures (v1.0 I believe) DLL.

I've searched for hours and have yielded very little in the way of answers.

We have pretty strict guidelines to use best practices in our code, so I'm not looking for a hack by any means.

If they have done away with this functionality, does anyone know of any equivalent alternatives?

Thanks in advance.